# Input quantity button plus and minus

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, sylius

In my cart page a user can increase or decrease the quantity of a product, let say I have 3 products added to my cart, when I click on the button quantity of the third product it increase or decrease the quantity the first product in the list.

Here the complete code:

```
    <table class="col-md-12">
    <thead style="font-size: 15px;">
    <tr>
    <th class="th-delate">{{ 'sylius.ui.delete_product'|trans }}</th>

    <th class="th-product">{{ 'sylius.ui.item'|trans }}</th>

    <th class="th-details">{{ 'sylius.ui.unit_price'|trans }}</th>
    <th class="th-price">{{ 'sylius.ui.qty'|trans }}</th>
    <th class="th-total th-add-to-cart">{{ 'sylius.ui.total'|trans }}</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for item in cart.items %}

<tr>
    <td class="th-delate"><a href="#"><button type="button" data-redirect="{{ path('sylius_shop_cart_summary') }}" data-url="{{ path('sylius_shop_ajax_cart_item_remove', {'id': item.id}) }}" class="ui circular icon button sylius-cart-remove-button" data-csrf-token="{{ csrf_token(item.id) }}"><i class="remove icon"></i></button></a></td>
    <td class="th-product">{% include '@SyliusShop/Product/_info.html.twig' with {'variant': product_variant} %}</td>
    <td style="text-align: center" class="th-details">
        {% if item.unitPrice != item.discountedUnitPrice %}
            <span class="sylius-regular-unit-price">{{ money.convertAndFormat(item.unitPrice) }}</span>
        {% endif %}
        <span style="color:#f00;font-weight: bold;font-size: 15px;" class="sylius-unit-price">{{ money.convertAndFormat(item.discountedUnitPrice) }}</span>
    </td>
    <td class="th-price">
        <div class="cart-plus-minus">
            <div class="numbers-row">
                <div onClick="var result = document.getElementById('qty'); var qty = result.value; if( !isNaN( qty ) &amp;&amp; qty &gt; 0 ) result.value--;return false;" class="dec qtybutton"><i class="fa fa-minus">&nbsp;</i></div>

                <input type="text" style="max-width: 65px; border-radius: 0" class="qty" title="Qty" value="{{ item.quantity }}" min="1" id="qty" name="sylius_cart[items][0][quantity]">


                <div onClick="var result = document.getElementById('qty'); var qty = result.value; if( !isNaN( qty )) result.value++;return false;" class="inc qtybutton"><i class="fa fa-plus">&nbsp;</i></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>

    <th style="color:#df3737;font-weight: bold;font-size: 15px;" class="td-add-to-cart"><a style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 15px;" href="#"> {{ money.convertAndFormat(item.subtotal) }}</a></th>
</tr>



    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>

    </table>
```

I would like to increase or decrease the quantity of the product I'm clicking on and not the first in the list.

I'm using symfony 3

Comment: you should give it a try and come back when you have a precise question on why you don't manage it / your error to solve (if not found in SO already)

Comment: Where is the list? In your example, there is only one input to qty..

Comment: post your complete code.

Comment: in a good day, i'll give you clues: you need to first build a list of several products. Then you'll realize you need to add id(s) to be able to interact each with another. Then you'll see you need a better event management, and probably separate js code from html. When you learnt how to bind an event like `click` to an element, you'll probably have a better idea for what to ask

Answer (score 1):

That is because when there is three items in your cart you have three inputs(type = text) with the id 'qty'. So it doesn't matter what incrementation element that you click on, the code refers to the first element out of the three elements. You'll have to provide different id values to each input here. It can be done dynamically.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are right , I have this problem because all the input have the same id  , I will try right now to fix it , I will let you know.

Comment: you sure do that :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div onClick="var result = document.getElementById('qty' ~ item.id); var qty 
= result.value; if( !isNaN( qty ) &amp;&amp; qty &gt; 0 ) result.value-
-;return false;" class="dec qtybutton"><i class="fa fa-minus">&nbsp;</i>
</div>

<input type="text" style="max-width: 65px; border-radius: 0" class="qty" 
title="Qty" value="{{ item.quantity }}" min="1" id="'qty' ~ item.id" 
name="sylius_cart[items][0][quantity]">

<div onClick="var result = document.getElementById('qty' ~ item.id); var qty 
= result.value; if( !isNaN( qty )) result.value++;return false;" class="inc 
qtybutton"><i class="fa fa-plus">&nbsp;</i></div>
```

Comment: I have tried with your example but it doesn't work . I have edit my code and it seems to be working well now. Can you please check my answer and tell me if everything seem to be alright for you. Thank you

Comment: My code is having syntax errors since I'm new to this. Anyways your answer is similar and should resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This example below seems to be working well:

```
            <div onClick="var result = document.getElementById('{{ item.id }}'); var qty = result.value; if( !isNaN( qty ) &amp;&amp; qty &gt; 0 ) result.value--;return false;" class="dec qtybutton"><i class="fa fa-minus">&nbsp;</i></div>

            <input type="text" style="max-width: 65px; border-radius: 0" class="qty" title="Qty" value="{{ item.quantity }}" min="1" id="{{ item.id }}" name="sylius_cart[items][][quantity]">


            <div onClick="var result = document.getElementById('{{ item.id }}'); var qty = result.value; if( !isNaN( qty )) result.value++;return false;" class="inc qtybutton"><i class="fa fa-plus">&nbsp;</i></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="field1">field 1
    <button type="button" id="sub" class="sub">-</button>
    <input type="number" id="1" value="1" min="1" max="3" />
    <button type="button" id="add" class="add">+</button>
</div>
<div id="field2">field 2
    <button type="button" id="sub2" class="sub">-</button>
    <input type="number" id="2" value="1" min="1" max="3" />
    <button type="button" id="add2" class="add">+</button>
</div>


    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add').click(function () {
        if ($(this).prev().val() < 3) {
          $(this).prev().val(+$(this).prev().val() + 1);
        }
    });
    $('.sub').click(function () {
        if ($(this).next().val() > 1) {
          if ($(this).next().val() > 1) $(this).next().val(+$(this).next().val() - 1);
        }
    });
    });
```